# How to update nested JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a `request_json` which will get updated different levels.

**Example:**

```
request_json = {"filter":""};

// I was updating it like(some where in script)..
request_json.filter = {div_id_1:[1,2,3]};

// Second time updating(some another place in script) is not working
request_json.filter = {div_id_2: ['abc','def']}; //not working.
```

**Expected output:**

```
request_json = {"filter":{div_id_1:[1,2,3], div_id_2: ['abc','def']}}
```

**Actual output:**

```
request_json = {"filter":{div_id_2: ['abc','def']}}
```

**Tried:**(not working)

```
request_json.filter.div_id_1 = {div_id_2: ['abc','def'];'def']}; //not working.
```

How to update this?

Comment: Can you update about what is your expecting result and what result you are getting, and even any error(s) that you are getting.

Comment: This code as you posted it will work. If there is an error, then we cannot see it here. Possibly because the 3rd line is running before the 2nd or first line.

Comment: @NotABot Please check. I have updated the question with exact way I'm doing in my code.

Comment: `request_json.filter.div_id_2 = ['abc','def']`

Comment: @Amadan I have tried it. There is no change. It is same as before and there is no error too.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong that is not represented in the question.

Comment: Okay, I will debug it once and update.

Comment: Try this   ``request_json = {"filter":""};

              request_json.filter = {div_id_1:[1,2,3]};

              request_json.filter.div_id_2 = ['abc','def'];``

Comment: What is "_nested JSON_" ..? JSON is a textual data exchange format, it doesn't implement objects and even less you can nest a string into itself.

Comment: @NotABot I have change `request_json = {"filter":""}` to `request_json = {"filter":{}}` and it works fine now!

Comment: @Teemu I mean `{key_1: {key_2:[data1, data2]}}` in this structure.

Comment: That's a JavaScript object, it has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: There is no such thing as "nested JSON" (or "JSON object", or "JSON array"). [JSON](https://json.org) is text, which in various programming languages is handled by the type `string`. It is a text representation of a data structure (that can be an object or an array or something else). In order to manipulate the encoded data, the JSON needs to be parsed. The result of parsing is a data structure similar to the one used to generate the JSON. Btw, there isn't any JSON in your question. Only JavaScript objects and arrays; they are not JSON (which is data), they are code.

Answer (score 0):

### JSON

First, a minor note.  You will get a lot of pushback around here using "JSON" to refer to arbitrary JS objects, even if people know what  you mean.  JSON is a string format used to represent data objects passed between systems.  It is *not* the object format itself.  Thus I will use `"request"` rather than `"request_json"` below.

### Why your code doesn't work

```js
request = {filter: ''};
// ... later
request.filter = {div_id_1: [1, 2, 3]};
// ... later still
request.filter = {div_id_2: ['abc', 'def']};
```

In each step of that, you *set* the `filter` value of your object.  On the first line, you set it to the empty string.  On the second line you set it to the object `{div_id_1: [1, 2, 3]}`, and on the third line you set it to the object `{div_id_2: ['abc', 'def']}`.  You have never told it to combine those objects into one.  If that's what you want it to do, you need to tell it so.

### The simplest fix

You can just change the third line to update the filter object with a new property:

```js
request = {filter: ''};
// ... later
request.filter = {div_id_1: [1, 2, 3]};
// ... later still
request.filter.div_id_2 = ['abc', 'def'];
```

If you know that the lines will always run in this order, and that this is all you need to do with the `filter`, this will work fine.

### Updating multiple times

But if your problem is more general, if, for instance, you want to be able to update the filter a number of times, but you're not sure which one might do so first, then it could help to write a function to handle the testing of whether the filter is already there and is an object.

It might look like this:

```js
const addToFilter = (request, key, val) => 
  request .filter = Object .assign (request .filter || {}, {[key]: val})

const request = {filter: ''}
// ... later
addToFilter (request, 'div_id_1', [1, 2, 3])
// ... later still
addToFilter (request, 'div_id_2', ['abc', 'def'])

console .log (request)
```

### Updating multiple properties at once

If in a single call, you might want to add multiple properties to your filter, the code can be even simpler:

```js
const addToFilter = (request, obj) => 
  request .filter = Object .assign (request .filter || {}, obj)

const request = {filter: ''}
// ... later
addToFilter (request, {div_id_1: [1, 2, 3]})
// ... later still
addToFilter (request, {div_id_2: ['abc', 'def'], meaningOfLife: 42})

console .log (request)
```

### Initial assignment

In each of these, I started with an empty string for the `filter` property.  If you need that for an external system -- if perhaps the system uses an empty string to say there is no filter but an object holding values otherwise -- then this is tolerable.  But it's far from ideal.  I would suggest that if you can, you should start without the `filter` property or with an empty object for `filter`.

### Mutation

This is still not code I would be proud of.  It does the job for now.  But I prefer to work with immutable data and here we continually mutate the `request` object and its `filter` property.  There are probably techniques that would let you do something functionally equivalent without mutating your data, but that's probably taking us too far afield, and would take much more knowledge of your code than I currently have.  But you might want to keep in mind techniques using immutable data.